# Best WPF panel to create custom control

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to design a custom control which contains one rich text box and a checkbox. I need to add this control at runtime in a stack panel. since the size of the stack panel can change, I want to make sure that the custom control takes full space, and the textbox inside the control increases in size accordingly.

I am getting a bit confused as to which panel would be the best bet for this custom control. Should I go for canvas or a dockpanel, or maybe even a grid?

Any suggestion is welcome.

EDIT
Below is the full code for the main page. It contains two sections, one for report preview, and another for report editing. That report editing section will count total subreports and create that many sections. So, the report editing pane needs to stack the controls nicely, and move other controls up and down to accommodate the expansion of the subreports. Subreports itself can vary in size.

Telerik's radExpander looked like a good idea at first, but main StackPanel does not consider the radExpander's visibility state. Right now, StackPanel uses full height even when radExpander is minimized.

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Panel.ZIndex="5">
        <Grid x:Name="MainArea" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel CanVerticallyScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <telerik:RadExpander x:Name="ReportSection" Height="120" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" Foreground="#FF0081A7" Header="Report Section Name" BorderBrush="#FF0081A7" BorderThickness="1"> 
                    <telerik:RadExpander.Content>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="AddToReport" Content="ADD TO REPORT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FF0081A7" Foreground="#FF0081A7" IsChecked="True" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" />
                            <telerik:RadRichTextBox x:Name="radRichTextBox" DocumentInheritsDefaultStyleSettings="True" Height="auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" IsSelectionMiniToolBarEnabled="True" IsSpellCheckingEnabled="True" IsContextMenuEnabled="True" Margin="10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </telerik:RadExpander.Content>
                </telerik:RadExpander>
                <telerik:RadExpander x:Name="ReportSection2" Height="120" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" Foreground="#FF0081A7" Header="Report Section Name" BorderBrush="#FF0081A7" BorderThickness="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" RenderTransformOrigin="0.493,0.856">
                    <telerik:RadExpander.Content>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="AddToReport2" Content="ADD TO REPORT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FF0081A7" Foreground="#FF0081A7" IsChecked="True" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" />
                            <telerik:RadRichTextBox x:Name="radRichTextBox2" DocumentInheritsDefaultStyleSettings="True" Height="auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" IsSelectionMiniToolBarEnabled="True" IsSpellCheckingEnabled="True" IsContextMenuEnabled="True" Margin="10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </telerik:RadExpander.Content>
                </telerik:RadExpander>
                <telerik:RadExpander x:Name="ReportSection3" Height="120" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" Foreground="#FF0081A7" Header="Report Section Name" BorderBrush="#FF0081A7" BorderThickness="1">
                    <telerik:RadExpander.Content>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="AddToReport3" Content="ADD TO REPORT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FF0081A7" Foreground="#FF0081A7" IsChecked="True" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" />
                            <telerik:RadRichTextBox x:Name="radRichTextBox3" DocumentInheritsDefaultStyleSettings="True" Height="auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" IsSelectionMiniToolBarEnabled="True" IsSpellCheckingEnabled="True" IsContextMenuEnabled="True" Margin="10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </telerik:RadExpander.Content>
                </telerik:RadExpander>
                <telerik:RadExpander x:Name="ReportSection4" Height="120" Margin="10,10,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" Foreground="#FF0081A7" Header="Report Section Name" BorderBrush="#FF0081A7" BorderThickness="1">
                    <telerik:RadExpander.Content>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="AddToReport4" Content="ADD TO REPORT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FF0081A7" Foreground="#FF0081A7" IsChecked="True" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" />
                            <telerik:RadRichTextBox x:Name="radRichTextBox4" DocumentInheritsDefaultStyleSettings="True" Height="auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" IsSelectionMiniToolBarEnabled="True" IsSpellCheckingEnabled="True" IsContextMenuEnabled="True" Margin="10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </telerik:RadExpander.Content>
                </telerik:RadExpander>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Have you tried *anything*? Neither panel is *better* than the other, it all depends on what context you need to use the panel. Experiment, and see what works for you.

Comment: I tried using both. Both comes with their own problems. I am inclining towards canvas, but not sure if that would give me best performance.

Comment: I would avoid Canvas if you're wanting your control to dynamically resize. What problems did you have starting with the grid control? And just to be clear: are you creating a Custom control, or a User control?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't go with a Canvas in this situation, can you provide some code so I can help with your layout?

Comment: Canvas is definitely not the answer here because it does no repositioning and no resizing. The op indicated he wants resizing, so the canvas can be excluded from the list.

Comment: Usually I make a clear drawing on how I want the control to look like and only then I start to select which panels to use for the layouting.

Comment: I am adding the code for the work that I have done. Currently it uses Telerik's expander control, but I want to use only existing panels, instead of third party.

Comment: By adding the edit your question is entirely different. Without it you looked like a beginner asking for some basic help.

Comment: I can understand. I have a severe headache right now, so I am basically as good as half drunk. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered before the edit
Based on your explanation you can only exclude the canvas from the list. 
The others have resizing and repositioning capabilities for the child controls within them.
It is even possible to have the same behavior by configuring one panel for instance a grid, to have the same effect as another panel like the dockpanel.
The gridpanel is probably the most versatile, but even then each and every panel has its use. The idea should be to use the right panel for the job so that the amount of xaml is limited and readable.

More information on the containers can be found here :
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/introduction-to-wpf-panels/

You did not give a concrete question for a certain positioning so then the answer can only scratch the surface too. But if you google around WPF panels and layouting and spend some time to read the material and do some exercises I am sure you'll understand them in a few hours of your time.

Comment: Positioning itself is not necessary. I can position the controls in different order. Idea is to keep sections of reports into rich text box, with option to add or remove the section from report. So, I want to show two panes, one with the preview of report, and another where all sections are editable. Currently I am trying a grid to simply put controls in different rows.

Comment: Also, I am adding the XAML that I have done till now in the main page. Currently it works fine with slight caveat. My stack panel consider the full height of the radExpander controls even when it is minimized.